socket.gethostbyname("...") and nslookup won't return the IP address of my subdomain in macOS
I'm currently writing a program in Python using sockets where I need to change the IP address frequently. I wanted to do this by creating a domain that points to an IP address. The idea was that I can change the IP address that should be point to there and hardcode socket.gethostbyname("myDomain.com") into my code.
That worked fine when I created the domain and tested it, but once I changed the IP address that should be point to it didn't work anymore. Now I also question whether it actually worked, because it won't anymore once I create a new subdomain.
I used https://freedns.afraid.org to create a "Type A" domain (actually a subdomain of a public domain, but I don't think that matters).
Tried this approach, because I want to be able to change the IP address that should be point to, in a compiled program, as the server admin (without users noticing it).
The following output is what I get when using socket.gethostbyname("..."):

"socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

I assumed that the provider takes some time until it updates the domain and the IP address it should point to, but it has been almost 3 hours (which is above the necessary update time of 1 hour).
Then I thought that my computer might have stored some data in the cache, so I found that terminal command to flush it (at least I think it flushes the correct thing):
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

I finally checked whether the domain actually exists or not. I tried to look up the subdomain on: https://www.nslookup.io and it actually found it and pointed to the IP address I set it to. But on my Mac is running macOS 15 (Sequoia) it wouldn't find it when I used nslookup in my Terminal.
I want to solve it by using this dynamic approach (if it is possible), but would there have been a better solution?

Population of DNS records can take up to 72 hours or more.

@RomeoNinov but then I wonder why the website would be able to find it

What is the MINTTL of that domain? When you make a query for your subdomain or some other nonexistent subdomain, what TTL does the returned negative reply have? For example, in dig asdf.example.com, what's the TTL of the returned SOA record?

@grawity_u1686 it says it has a TTL of 1 hour. For your example website I couldn't find a TTL value. For my website I got a time out.
